# Why aren't these @-moz-keyframes working?

Tags: css, css-animations

I need someone to point my nose as to why @-moz-keyframes isn't working. I have the latest FF installed. So if someone help that would be great.

```
@-moz-keyframes accTextMove {
25% { margin: 50px 0 0 380px; opacity: 0; } 100% { margin: 50px 0 0 30px; opacity: 1;         }
}

@-moz-keyframes focusTextMove {
0% { opacity: 0; } 50% { opacity: 0; } 100% { opacity: 1; }
}

@-moz-keyframes accFadeTextMove {
0% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: scale(.5); } 100% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: scale(1); }
}

@-moz-keyframes focusFadeTextMove {
0% { opacity: 0; } 35% { opacity: 0; margin: 115px 0 0 53px; } 100% { opacity: 1; margin: 115px 0 0 140px; }
}

<div id="textIntroArea">
    <span id="accFade">Accounting</span>
    <span id="focusFade">with focus</span>
    <span id="acc">Accounting</span>
    <span id="focus">with focus</span>
</div>
```

If you can see what I've missed that'll be great.

Comment: Can you include the CSS for #accFade, #focusFade, #acc, and #focus?

Comment: That was all I needed! I had forgotten to ad the:

    -moz-animation: accTextMove 3s ease;

To the #accFade etc. Thanks for asking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [css @-moz-keyframes animation not working on firefox 18.0.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713191/css-moz-keyframes-animation-not-working-on-firefox-18-0-1)

Answer (score 0):

-moz prefix doesn't support in new version of FF ( 18.0.1)

Check this question answer

[css @-moz-keyframes animation not working on firefox 18.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713191/css-moz-keyframes-animation-not-working-on-firefox-18-0-1)