# css @-moz-keyframes animation not working on firefox 18.0.1

Tags: html, firefox, css, webkit-transform, css-animations

css @-moz-keyframes  animation on  firefox 18.0.1  is not working,

I have checked this animation on previous version( forgot version previous number) , it was working,

Here is the animation

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">

            @-webkit-keyframes animation {
                0% { -webkit-transform:translate(100px,100px) scale(1); }
                50% { -webkit-transform:translate(00px,00px)  scale(2); }
                100% { -webkit-transform:translate(100px,100px)  scale(1); }
            }

            @-moz-keyframes animation_m {
                0% { -moz-transform:translate(100px,100px)  scale(1); }
                50% { -moz-transform: translate(00px,00px) scale(2); }
                100% { -moz-transform:translate(100px,100px)  scale(1); }
            }

            .cc1{
                -webkit-animation-name: "animation";
                -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;

                -moz-animation-name: "animation_m";
                -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
                -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
            }

            #id1,#ci1{
                position:absolute;
                top:0px;
                left:0px;
            }

        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload=function(){
                var e=document.getElementById("ci1");
                var ctx=e.getContext("2d");
                ctx.fillStyle="#f00";
                ctx.fillRect(0,0,90,90);
            }
        </script>
    <body>
        <div id="id1" class="cc1">
            <canvas width="100" height="100" id="ci1" ></canvas>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is it a Firefox bug?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Firefox 18 (and Opera, and IE10, and many others in the near future) expects the W3C property [without the vendor prefix](http://paulrouget.com/e/unprefixing-in-firefox-16/). Make sure to add the following block:

```
@keyframes animation_m {
    0% { transform:translate(100px,100px)  scale(1); }
    50% { transform: translate(00px,00px) scale(2); }
    100% { transform:translate(100px,100px)  scale(1); }
}

.cc1 {
    animation-name: animation_m;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    timing-function: linear;
}
```

Note that the `-moz-transform` properties were also changed to `transform`.

You should **always** include the vendor-prefix-free version for all prefixed CSS properties. I would also recommend giving your CSS styles and animation names more descriptive names.

Comment: Did you see my edit with the `.cc1` class? The `animation-name` property should match your `keyframes` definition, but it was missing the `_m` postfix.

Comment: its still not working with your edit in .cc1;
no, its not missing _m postfix, it is there

Comment: Here's a fiddle that works in the latest Chrome and FF: http://jsfiddle.net/EghZs/ Does it work for you?

Comment: its working now!, thanks for help, it seams **-moz** prefix  doesn't support in new version of FF..

Comment: Great! Yep, many browsers (including Webkit) will soon drop support for vendor prefixes, so you should always include the standard non-prefix version.

Comment: The -moz prefix is supported fine in Firefox 18.  The original source pasted in this bug is just not valid CSS, as the web console in Firefox tells you.  In particular, the animation name is an identifier, not a string, and hence shouldn't be in quotes.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is in this line

```
-moz-animation-name: "animation_m";
```

in **google chrome** if you write your animation name in double quote ("") it takes as identifier but in **firefox** it is consider as a string , not the identifier so mention animation name without double quote...

```
    -moz-animation-name: animation_m;
```