# CSS3 transform not working on Firefox, why?

Tags: html, css

Hi here's my code in JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/qnbxaLwh/

Here's the simple HTML

```
<span class="arrow">xssss</span>
```

Here's my CSS

```
.arrow {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-right:10px;
    bottom: 5%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
    -moz-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
    -ms-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
    -o-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
    animation: bounce 2s infinite;
}
 @-webkit-keyframes bounce {
     0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
     -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
     -moz-transform: translateY(0);
     -ms-transform: translateY(0);
     -o-transform: translateY(0);
     transform: translateY(0);
    }
     40% {
     -webkit-transform: translateY(-6px);
     -moz-transform: translateY(-6px);
     -ms-transform: translateY(-6px);
     -o-transform: translateY(-6px);
     transform: translateY(-6px);
    }
     60% {
     -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px);
     -moz-transform: translateY(-5px);
     -ms-transform: translateY(-5px);
     -o-transform: translateY(-5px);
     transform: translateY(-5px);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes bounce {
     0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
     -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
     -moz-transform: translateY(0);
     -ms-transform: translateY(0);
     -o-transform: translateY(0);
     transform: translateY(0);
    }
     40% {
     -webkit-transform: translateY(-6px);
     -moz-transform: translateY(-6px);
     -ms-transform: translateY(-6px);
     -o-transform: translateY(-6px);
     transform: translateY(-6px);
    }
     60% {
     -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px);
     -moz-transform: translateY(-5px);
     -ms-transform: translateY(-5px);
     -o-transform: translateY(-5px);
     transform: translateY(-5px);
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes bounce {
     0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
     -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
     -moz-transform: translateY(0);
     -ms-transform: translateY(0);
     -o-transform: translateY(0);
     transform: translateY(0);
    }
     40% {
     -webkit-transform: translateY(-6px);
     -moz-transform: translateY(-6px);
     -ms-transform: translateY(-6px);
     -o-transform: translateY(-6px);
     transform: translateY(-6px);
    }
     60% {
     -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px);
     -moz-transform: translateY(-5px);
     -ms-transform: translateY(-5px);
     -o-transform: translateY(-5px);
     transform: translateY(-5px);
    }
}
@keyframes bounce {
     0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
     -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
     -moz-transform: translateY(0);
     -ms-transform: translateY(0);
     -o-transform: translateY(0);
     transform: translateY(0);
    }
     40% {
     -webkit-transform: translateY(-6px);
     -moz-transform: translateY(-6px);
     -ms-transform: translateY(-6px);
     -o-transform: translateY(-6px);
     transform: translateY(-6px);
    }
     60% {
     -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px);
     -moz-transform: translateY(-5px);
     -ms-transform: translateY(-5px);
     -o-transform: translateY(-5px);
     transform: translateY(-5px);
    }
}
```

I've been trying for hours but I don't understand why it's not working on firefox. I tried rearranging and googling some stuffs but nothing works.

Comment: Did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713191/css-moz-keyframes-animation-not-working-on-firefox-18-0-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `position:relative;` to `position:absolute;`

working fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/qnbxaLwh/1/

- you can remove keyframe for firefox, firefox no longer uses for 2 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use position relative, try using some tools like this -> https://coveloping.com/tools/css-animation-generator

According to the code that they use (working crossbrowser) you're using wrong prefix for you animations (-moz-animation-name, for example...)

Answer (score 0):

Please update css

```css
.arrow {
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 padding-right:10px;
 bottom: 5%;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
    top: 0;
 -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
 -moz-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
 -ms-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
 -o-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
 animation: bounce 2s infinite;
}
 @-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  -o-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
 }
  40% {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-6px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-6px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-6px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-6px);
  transform: translateY(-6px);
 }
  60% {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-5px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-5px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-5px);
  transform: translateY(-5px);
 }
}
@-moz-keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  -o-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
 }
  40% {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-6px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-6px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-6px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-6px);
  transform: translateY(-6px);
 }
  60% {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-5px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-5px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-5px);
  transform: translateY(-5px);
 }
}
@-ms-keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  -o-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
 }
  40% {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-6px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-6px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-6px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-6px);
  transform: translateY(-6px);
 }
  60% {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-5px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-5px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-5px);
  transform: translateY(-5px);
 }
}
@keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  -o-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
 }
  40% {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-6px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-6px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-6px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-6px);
  transform: translateY(-6px);
 }
  60% {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-5px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-5px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-5px);
  transform: translateY(-5px);
 }
}
```