# Firefox transform:scale on hover issue

Tags: html, css, firefox

When applying transform:scale to my element, the border-colors get messed up. Would like to know if this is a known issue and has a solution? If I remove the scale the animation works fine and borders return to normal. I have also tried both ways, when scaling up and down the issue persists. Tried zoom, transform-origin, nothing seems to fix this weird issue. Also this has no issues in chrome.
[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j2udewyx/4/)

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.player-chromecast {
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 22px;
  height: 17px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
}

.player-chromecast:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1)
}

.broadcast {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 18px;
  height: 19px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
  left: -2px;
}

.broadcast:after {
  content: '';
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  background-color: white;
}

.reception {
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}

.first-bar {
  height: 6px;
  width: 6px;
  top: 8px;
}

.second-bar {
  height: 11px;
  width: 11px;
  top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="player-chromecast">
  <div class="broadcast">
    <div class="reception first-bar"></div>
    <div class="reception second-bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: check out this link   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28805220/css3-transform-not-working-on-firefox-why. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background-color: #20262e;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.player-chromecast:hover .reception {
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: transparent;
}
p {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.player-chromecast {
border-left: 1px solid #fff !important;
border: 2px solid white;
border-radius: 4px;
width: 22px;
height: 17px;
position: relative;
margin: 10px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #fff !important;
}

.player-chromecast:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1)
}

.broadcast {
  background-color: #20262e;
  width: 18px;
  height: 19px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
  left: -2px;
}

.broadcast:after {
  content: '';
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  background-color: white;
}

.reception {
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}

.first-bar {
  height: 6px;
  width: 6px;
  border-left: 0px;
  top: 8px;
}

.second-bar {
  height: 11px;
  width: 11px;
  border-left: 0px;
  top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div class="player-chromecast">
  <div class="broadcast">
    <div class="reception first-bar"></div>
    <div class="reception second-bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please check now in firefox or any other browsers it working correctly i mean border is not there on hover .....Let me know if you still get same bugs